# Change the link color of a labeled item with custom label text

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, color

I found the code in the following page:

https://joerglenhard.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/labeled-item-with-custom-label-text/

In author's own words: "*an item list where each `\item` is labeled, so I can reference it later on. Instead of a simple numeric label, I want some text to be displayed at the position of the label and the same text at each position where I reference the label*".

In the following MWE the custom label text appears with red color since the `linkcolor` of the `hyperref` package is `red`. What I want is to modify the color of the custom label texts to green (to the whole document) without affecting the other settings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref,
    linkcolor=red,
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdftitle={Dossier de Candidature, MCF60},
    pdfauthor={Dimitrios S. Anagnostou}]{hyperref}

\newcounter{reqcount}
\newcommand{\descitem}[1]{%
  \item[R\ref*{#1}] \refstepcounter{reqcount}\label{#1}
}
\newcommand{\descref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{R\ref*{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{foo:section}\label{foo:section}

\begin{itemize}
 \descitem{item:xyz} foo
 \descitem{item:abc} bar
\end{itemize}

As defined in \descref{item:xyz} and opposed to \descref{item:abc} of Section \ref{foo:section}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

So in this example R1 and R2 should be green while 1 should stay red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref,
    linkcolor=red,
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdftitle={Dossier de Candidature, MCF60},
    pdfauthor={Dimitrios S. Anagnostou}]{hyperref}

\newcounter{reqcount}
\newcommand{\descitem}[1]{%
  \item[R\ref*{#1}] \refstepcounter{reqcount}\label{#1}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\descref}[1]{%
  {\def\@linkcolor{green}\hyperref[#1]{R\ref*{#1}}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{foo:section}\label{foo:section}

\begin{itemize}
 \descitem{item:xyz} foo
 \descitem{item:abc} bar
\end{itemize}

As defined in \descref{item:xyz} and opposed to \descref{item:abc} of Section \ref{foo:section}.

\end{document}
```

[image]